# Could the Russian fleet go via northern route to Port Arthur instead of via Cape of Good Hope?

Tags: military, japan, russia, naval, russo-japanese-war

Was there a route via the north of Russia that [Admiral Rozhestvensky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinovy_Rozhestvensky) could have passed (maybe during the summer months) instead of the seven month odyssey of going through Cape of Good Hope around Africa and then through Indian Ocean and South China Sea to reach Vladivostok and eventually [Port Arthur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCshunkou_District).

[image: Route of the Baltic Fleet]

Comment: The simple answer is no. At that time one could not pass the North East passage in one navigation, and without powerful icebreakers (which did not exist).

Answer (score 17):

Absolutely no. The first time when the [North-East passage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northeast_Passage#History) was made in one navigation (that is in less that one year) was [in 1932](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northeast_Passage#After_the_Russian_Revolution) using icebreakers.
And this was just an experimental expedition. In 1905 Russia had no enough icebreakers of sufficient power, not even mentioning other difficulties, like coaling stations on the way.

Comment: Note that these days there *is* a regular ice-free route through during summer months. Those global warming hoaxers are nothing if not thorough. ;-)

Comment: The first ship to make that passage, *Vega* in 1878-1879, was not an ice-breaker, and had only an auxiliary steam engine. It was only 200 km shy of making the passage in one summer.  The lack of coaling stations and the risk of ships not built to withstand that kind of forces were probably the real problems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vega_Expedition

Comment: @andejoins: "Only" 200 km short is not counted in such questions, like "only 200 meters short" is not counted when you climb Everest.